# Hint in EditText lefts empty space on focus

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a `EditText` with longer multiple lines hint and when I focus on this `EditText`, hint disappears but lefts empty space around new text which I don't want. I have already tried to fix it with `android:gravity="bottom"`, but empty space still remains.

Here is the code:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/addextra_basedon_value"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:hint="@string/placeholder_acting_on"
android:gravity="bottom" />
```

And pictures:

before

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: Could be the gravity attribute? you are asking the edittext to be aligned bottom.

Comment: If there is no gravity attribute, then text is centered in that area and has empty space not only on top, but bellow also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the behaviour of the `EditText` when focused like this:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    editText.setHint("");
                    editText.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I have already tried same thing except I was missing editText.setText("");.